# How do I change the size of button in Xcode 11.1 with Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I copied my code from Apple Watch project to iOS project and now everything is tiny.

Comment: Please post the code that is relevant to your question. Currently as it stands it will be hard for someone to help you without seeing the code that you are using. You should create a minimal, reproducible example, for more information see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

Add `.frame()` modifier after button:

```swift
Button("name") {
  // code
}
.frame(width: 32.0, height: 32.0)
```

Comment: Please don’t post screenshots of code, please edit your question and add the relevant code.

Comment: Ah, Im sorry. Won't in the future